# How to make a mysql query from c# and save it in a variable?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want my c # program to take the data from the mysql database and save that data to a variable type double. I was trying but I still can't do it.

`

```
MySqlDataReader read = null;
            
string selectCmd = "SELECT Saldo from cuentas where NoCuenta=" + cuenta + ";";
            
MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
            
MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(selectCmd, MyConn2);
            
MyConn2.Open();
            
read = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
            
MessageBox.Show("read: " +read);
            
bool saldoI = read.Read();
            
double saldo = Convert.ToDouble(saldoI);
           
 MessageBox.Show("Aqui se muestra el saldo inicial " + read);
            
double saldoFinal = saldo - monto;
```

`

I know that as I am transforming it from a bool type variable it returns a 1, but I require that it return the data type double.
Example: 300.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
if (read.Read())
    double saldo = Convert.ToDouble(reader[0]);
```

The `read.Read()` return value, returns true if there is indeed a returned row from your query and false if there isn't or you read them all.

To actually get the data you need to access the current row's column [in the data reader.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Example in the link above:

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
        }
    }
}
```